# Expanding documentView in NSScrollView

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsscrollview

I have an `NSSplitView` that contains 2 side-by-side panes, and in the right-hand pane, there is an `NSScrollView`. I have a separate XIB file that contains the view (`inspectorView`) that I want to embed in the scroll view, which I do like so:

```
self.scrollView.documentView = inspectorView
```

This works perfectly, however, when I make the split view pane a bit wider my `inspectorView` doesn't grow horizontally to fill the space.  Using `-NSShowAllviews YES` I've confirmed that the scroll view is correctly resizing, however, the `inspectorView` remains the same width as it was when it was originally assigned to `scrollView.documentView`. Herein lies my problem... I want it to expand to fill the split view width.

I'm using autolayout for everything and all of my views are created using XIBs. The only thing I'm doing programatically is setting the `documentView` property of the scroll view.

If I was adding the `inspectorView` as a subview, then it is easy to add constraints that tell it to grow to fill the parent view. However, I'm not sure what the equivalent mechanism is when setting the `documentView` of an `NSScrollView`. Any suggestions?  Thanks.

**Edit**

As is often the way, 20 minutes after I posted this, I discovered one way to get it to work, which is to set the auto resizing mask and then get it to translate that mask into constraints.

```
inspectorView.autoresizingMask = .ViewWidthSizable
inspectorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
self.scrollView.documentView = inspectorView
```

Normally, I'm setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, not `true`. Anyway, as I said, this seems to work however I'm not yet convinced this is the *right* way. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pin the document-view's left and right edges to the corresponding edges of its superview - the scroll view's `contentView` (an `NSClipView` instance):

```
// docView and scrollView defined elsewhere.
// In both cases translatesAutoresizingMaskInConstraints is set to false.

scrollView.documentView = docView

let viewsDict = ["docView" : docView]
scrollView.contentView.addConstraints(
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[docView]|", 
        options: .allZeros, 
        metrics: nil, 
        views: viewsDict) 
)
```

That should work in your case, where it sounds like you've already got the vertical size of the document view behaving as you require.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.